# .NET ApplicationSettings - Where's it loading the settings from?

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings, appsettings

I have settings that were originally scoped as User settings. I notice that the main .config that lives in the same directory as the assembly is being ignored by .NET. If I change any setting it still always ends up with the default values at run-time. I was unable to find a copy of the config file in User AppData. I changed the settings' scope to Application and yet .NET is still ignoring the config file.

Where is the file it's trying to load instead? How can I get it to only use the .config file in the assembly's directory?

Comment: You can't fix this problem. There's no solution for this. Use text file to save data in it.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. I came across this problem and it's just a problem with the config file where the configsection is probably not properly referenced in <configsections> or specified in the <applicationSettings>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio to run your application, visual studio regenerates the settings file every time you complete a recompile.

So if you change your settings within the application and rebuild & launch within visual studio, the settings file will revert to what values are stored in the visual studio project.

Comment: But if there's a properly configured appname.exe.config those default values hardcoded in the assembly will not be the active ones anymore and the values in the config file will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Configuration manager to read settings from config file, it has to load data from appname.exe.config file. Try this code (you have to add reference to system.configuration assembly)

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settings-name"];
```

Comment: I'm using the MySettings.Default.MyOption method(partial class generated by VS and has a designer). The documentation claims it loads the config file in the background without an explicit invokation.